# Angular parent and child states same controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I have a list of items (state is /items), and beside I have the details of an item (state is /items/:id).
What is the best practice to do it? Separate controllers, or use the same one?

```
class ctrl{
    constructor($http, $stateParams, $scope){
        $http.get(...).then((res)=> {
            this.items = res.data;
        });

        $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", (e, state, params) => {
            if(params.id){
                this.currentItem = this.items[params.id];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The stateChangeSuccess is fired only, and if I have id in the url, the items list still empty.
I tried to register the event inside the promise, but it's not fired when trying to access the id in the url directly.

Thanks!

Comment: use the same but be sure it routes as priority based. `/items` if not then `/items/:id`

Comment: Thats is my problem. How can I set this priority?

Comment: So put it in same controller.

Comment: I did it. But when I need to take the item from the list, I cannot be sure the list already loaded.

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Perform check based on Parameter.

Comment: When accessing /items/:id, this event is fired only once, and with the id. Then the array is empty.